# Different types of closure syntax in swift - which one is correct?

Tags: ios, swift, closures, swift3, completionhandler

I'm pretty curious which one of these syntax statements is (more) correct.
Playground happily compiles both cases.

**Method 1**

```
// copied from SO and this appears clear to me
UIView.animate(
    withDuration: 3.0,
    animations: {

    },
    completion: { (Bool) in
        // completion code
    }
)
```

**Method 2**

```
UIView.animate(
    withDuration: 3.0,
    animations: {

        // code

    }) {(Bool) in
      // code when finished?
      // argument label completion missing?
    }
```

Why rounded brackets in 2nd method are closed before last argument stated? Or is that another implementation of `UIView.animation`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The difference between both methods is following:

**Method 1:** ***Regular*** closure

**Method 2:** ***Trailing closure***. 
**Last** closure parameter in the signature of a function can be written in **shorter syntax**. If the second parameter would be `completion`, and `animations` parameter would be the last, the trailing closure would apply to animations etc.
So it has to stand as the last (or the only) closure parameter.

If you miss a `completion` label, you are free to type it like this:

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 3.0, animations: {

 }) {(completion: Bool) in

 }
```

For completion of your question as well: It is the **same implementation** of an identical function, but a **different syntax**.

Comment: Was going to say that, but you stated it nicely. The advantage of using the trailing closure is that it often results in cleaner looking code.

Comment: Well after I took a look again, it appeared to me cleaner looking too :) Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

Both of them are correct.

1. It is the usual closure syntax in a function call.
2. It represents a **Trailing closure**.

> If you need to pass a closure expression to a function as the
>   function’s final argument and the closure expression is long, it can
>   be useful to write it as a trailing closure instead. A trailing
>   closure is written after the function call’s parentheses, even though
>   it is still an argument to the function. When you use the trailing
>   closure syntax, you don’t write the argument label for the closure as
>   part of the function call.

You can read more about trailing closures from https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Closures.html

Comment: Thank you, so we shouldn't write arg. label within trailing closure? Or just it is not needed?

Comment: There is no scope for writing argument label with trailing closure. "completion:" need not be written. The body of the trailing closure is written outside the method calling brackets i.e UIView.animate(...){trailing closure body}